# Abstract over the "copy" function from a data class

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-function-type, dataclasses

Let's say that I have a `sealed interface`, and each implementation of the interface is a `data class`

```kotlin
sealed interface Animal {
  val name: String
  val age: Int
}

data class Cat(
    override val name: String, 
    override val age: Int,
) : Animal

data class Dog(
    override val name: String, 
    override val age: Int,
) : Animal

// Possibly many more animals
```

I want to have a function which let's me rename any `Animal` and return the same type of Animal.

```kotlin
fun <T : Animal> T.rename(newName: String): T
```

It's surprisingly difficult to come up with an implementation for this. The best I could do is this, which is extraordinarily redundant and results in a compiler warning `Unchecked cast: Animal to T` even though we know this cast is guaranteed to succeed.

```kotlin
fun <T : Animal> T.rename(newName: String): T = when(this) {
  is Cat -> copy(name=newName)
  is Dog -> copy(name=newName)
  // and so on for many other animals
  else -> throw IllegalStateException(::class.toString())
} as T
```

Another thing I tried is to add `copy(name: String)` to `Animal`, but the `copy` function generated by Kotlin doesn't count as an implementation.

```kotlin
sealed interface Animal {
    val name: String
    val age: Int
    fun copy(name: String): Animal
}

// Class 'Cat' is not abstract and does not implement abstract member public abstract fun copy(name: String): Animal defined in com.example.Animal
data class Cat(
    override val name: String,
    override val age: Int,
) : Animal
```

Seems like I ran into a limitation of Kotlin's type system. Is there any way to implement the `rename` function without manually implementing it for each subtype of `Animal`? And without casting?

Answer (score 3):

The full signature of the data class `copy` function would look similar to this:

```
sealed interface Animal {
    val name: String
    val age: Int
    fun copy(name: String = this.name, age: Int = this.age): Animal
}
```

But this causes another error:

```
error: function 'copy' generated for the data class has default values for parameters, and conflicts with member of supertype 'Animal'
```

In fact, it's not possible for the `copy` function to be an override: see [discussion](https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/how-to-avoid-warning-when-overriding-copy-function-with-data-class/5368) and [YouTrack issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-19618).

Instead of using a `when` block, you can add the `copy` to the data class using a different function name:

```
sealed interface Animal {
    val name: String
    val age: Int
    fun with(name: String = this.name, age: Int = this.age): Animal
}

data class Cat(
    override val name: String,
    override val age: Int,
) : Animal {
    override fun with(name: String, age: Int): Cat = copy(name = name, age = age)
}

inline fun <reified T : Animal> T.rename(newName: String): T = with(name = newName) as T
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't buy you much, as it just moves the code duplication to a different place.

If you want to keep your current code as it is, note that when you use a sealed interface, the `when` is exhaustive, so you don't need an `else` part, and you're guaranteed you won't miss a subtype.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, you won't be able to do this directly. You could try to declare the following function in `Animal`:

```kotlin
fun copy(name: String = this.name, age: Int = this.age): Animal
```

But this won't work for two reasons.

1. It won't compile; see [k314159's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77647767/6395627) for the error.
2. You'll run into issues if and when you want to add properties to an implementation of `Animal` but not to `Animal` itself.

If you're okay with using reflection, however, then the following may work for you.

```kotlin
import kotlin.reflect.full.*

@Suppress("unchecked_cast")
fun <T : Animal> T.rename(name: String): T {
    require(this::class.isData) { "${this::class} is not a data class" }

    val copyFun = this::class.declaredMemberFunctions.single { it.name == "copy" }
    val instanceParam = copyFun.instanceParameter!!
    val nameParam = copyFun.findParameterByName("name")!!

    val args = mapOf(instanceParam to this, nameParam to name)
    return copyFun.callBy(args) as T // unchecked cast is still necessary
}
```

Note this will require adding the [kotlin-reflect](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reflection.html#jvm-dependency) library to your project. And I believe it will restrict you to Android/JVM.

Answer (score 2):

I have come across the very same problem and came up with a workaround that has the identical limitation that you point out.

```
sealed interface Animal {
    val name: String
    val age: Int
    
    fun copy(
        name: String = this.name,
        age: Int = this.age,
    ): Animal
}

data class Cat(
    override val name: String,
    override val age: Int,
    val color: String,
) : Animal {
    override fun copy(
        name: String,
        age: Int,
    ): Cat = Cat(name, age, color)

}

data class Dog(
    override val name: String,
    override val age: Int,
    val breed: String,
) : Animal {
    override fun copy(
        name: String,
        age: Int,
    ): Dog = copy(name = name, age = age, breed = breed)
}
```

- the implementing `data` classes' props *must not* be the same as the ones defined on the interface (there should be some other prop to avoid conflicting definition)
- the implementation is easy, but still has to be done for each subclass

This `copy` method behaves similarly to the one that we get for `data` classes, so you can modify any property of the interface (not just the `name`).

I created a [github repo](https://github.com/feczkob/kotlin-interface-copy) to demonstrate the usage.
I would point that out that this solution is better in my opinion than using `when` expressions everywhere.